# Как проверить строку наличие кириллицы и деффиса?

Tags: java, методы

При вводе пользователем ФИО, проверила на кириллицу и деффис.
Без регулярных выражений.
Можете подсказать?.

Введите полное имя: Александр КОн ала
Введенная строка не является ФИО
Фамилия: Александр
Имя: КОн
Отчество: ала

Запутался окончательно)

Answer (score 1):

Проверяем на наличие Кириллицы:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.next();

    System.out.println(isValid(s));
    // isValid("hello") -> true
    // isValid("привет") -> false
}

public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(s.charAt(i)).equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC) || 
            s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Я тут окончательно запутался) в  решение этой задачи. Народил такой код

Comment: На самом деле все просто. В функции `main` создаем сканер, вводим строку. Вызываем метод `isValid()` и передаем туда нашу введенную строку. В методе `isValid` для каждого символа этой строки проверяем являеться ли он в юникод блоке с киррилицей (как он устроен точно я не знаю, нашел в докумментации). Если там есть русские буквы, то просто возвращает `false`, что значит, что строка не валидная.

Comment: Посмотрите пжл, мой чудо код) Я ушел от булиона. Но стало не лучшее(

Comment: @AlexOrlov, попозже гляну

Comment: Cпасибо, как будет время! Буду благодарен.

Comment: Вопрос снят! Сделал!Еще раз Благодарю.

Comment: @AlexOrlov, да-да, кстати. Забыл посмотреть :)